# Cannot Edit model fields/Django Signal to update image likes wont work/

Tags: django, database, signals

I implemented a signal with an m2mchanged receiver to update a PositiveIntegerField in my Image model. This PositiveIntegerField is for total_likes of the image but upon implementing the signal I realized that the total_likes field did not change from zero. I started experimenting and found that this value will not change even if I change it in the shell or the admin page itself.

I dont think this is a problem with the signal/receiver but rather something else happening that wont let the value be change in the database.

Here is My code.

## models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                        related_name='images_created')
 title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,
                        blank=True)
 url = models.URLField()
 image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
 description = models.TextField(blank=True)
 created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)




 def __str__(self):
     return self.title

 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     if not self.slug:
         self.slug = slugify(self.title)
         super(Image, self).save(*args, *kwargs)

 users_like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                    related_name='images_liked',
                                    blank=True)
 def get_absolute_url(self):
     return reverse('images:detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])

 tags = TaggableManager()
 total_likes = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True, default=0)
```

I can post the signals.py files or any other code if necessary.
Thank you!

## Solution

My problem was in my overridden save method, I changed it to the following.

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Image, self).save(*args, *kwargs)
    elif self.slug != slugify(self.title):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Image, self).save(*args, *kwargs)
    else:
        super(Image, self).save(*args, *kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct and simple solution here will be:

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:  # don't allow to change slug after object created
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: even better. Thank you Do you suggest not allowing the slug to be changed after object creation?

Comment: Becuase it unique identifire, like the 'id', so you shouldn't change it. In case if you want to be able to change it - just replace 'if not self.id' by 'if not self.slug'.